# American 'd' sound is sometimes retroflex?

Tags: american-english, phonology, phonetics, sounds, consonants

In fast-paced American English speech, I've observed that the 'd' sound in certain words containing -rd- consonant clusters such as 'hurdle' and 'border' seems to be pronounced as a voiced retroflex flap **[ɽ]** rather than a voiced alveolar flap **[ɾ]** or the standard voiced alveolar plosive **[d]**. I'm curious to know if this phenomenon is acknowledged by linguists. I've heard that in some North Germanic languages like Swedish, the combination of /r/ with dental consonants results in retroflex consonant realizations. Could a similar pattern be present in American English?

Comment: Also see [Place of articulation of /t/ and /d/ in words like "part", "cord", "weird" in Standard AmE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/433660/place-of-articulation-of-t-and-d-in-words-like-part-cord-weird-in-st)

Comment: It depends on whether the speaker retracts the chin when producing the {vowel}+ /r/, I think.